# Get sum of property values within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend, reduce

I am trying to get an object as output using JavaScript reduce function. It's working, if I define an object `{ageTotal: 0}` as the second argument. How can I implement this sum of age without defining a second argument property only using an empty object `{}`.

```
const users = [
  { name: 'Tyler', age: 28},
  { name: 'Mikenzi', age: 26},
  { name: 'Blaine', age: 30 }
];

// output as a *int*
const sumAge = users.reduce((totals, current) => {
  return totals + current.age;
}, 0);
console.log(sumAge);

// output as *object*
function getUserData (users) {
  return users.reduce((data, user) => {
    data.ageTotal += user.age
    return data;
  }, { ageTotal: 0 });
}
console.log(getUserData(users));
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble understanding the question. What result do you want? What's the problem you're having getting that result? Or what do you want to change about the code?

Comment: If you read my post, I hope you will get it. The title is a bit confusing.

Comment: You can use the same code as `sumAge`. Instead of returning the int, return an object with that as a property: `const getUserData = users => ({ ageTotal: users.reduce((totals, current) =>  totals + current.age, 0)
})`

Comment: @MamunurRashid - I read your post before posting the comment. Twice, in fact. You really shouldn't assume people haven't read your post.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) while incrementing to add current age value to accumulator property `ageTotal` (if it exists, or set it to 0, otherwise):

```
data.ageTotal = (data.ageTotal || 0) + user.age
```

Following is a quick demo:

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Tyler', age: 28},
  { name: 'Mikenzi', age: 26},
  { name: 'Blaine', age: 30 }
];

// output as *object*
function getUserData (users) {
  return users.reduce((data, user) => {
    data.ageTotal = (data.ageTotal || 0) + user.age
    return data;
  }, {});
}
console.log(getUserData(users));
```

Or, if you seek to make your syntax more concise:

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Tyler', age: 28},
  { name: 'Mikenzi', age: 26},
  { name: 'Blaine', age: 30 }
];

// output as *object*
const getUserData = users =>
  users.reduce((data, {age}) => 
    (data.ageTotal = (data.ageTotal || 0) + age, data), {});

console.log(getUserData(users));
```

Comment: Thanks @Yevgen Gorbunkov